# Simple model of computation with homoiconicity

Tags: lo.logic, computability, pl.programming-languages, lambda-calculus

Is there a simple model of computation with [homoiconicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity)?

It would also be nice if, like beta reduction in lambda calculus, every step in execution yields a new valid program.

Besides the lack of homoiconicity, another annoyance of lambda calculus is the necessity of checking for free variables when performing substitution.

Comment: why do you say that lambda calculus lacks homoiconity? regarding free variables, you may use de Bruijn indices

Comment: In lambda calculus, you can't access the contents of a piece of code as data without executing it. (Sorry I'm not sure how to put that more technically.)

Comment: yep, you are right. I see now.

Comment: The semi-canonical way of eliminating free variables entirely is by using [combinatory logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic) instead. That doesn't help with your main question, though.

Comment: I don't fully understand the original question, but it might be useful to look at languages like [Template Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Template_Haskell), [Converge](http://convergepl.org/) or [MetaOCaml](http://www.metaocaml.org), which I'd say are homoiconic (in subtly different ways). They are all based around providing explicit support for quasi-quotes which is a convenient mechanism (API) for abstract syntax trees.

Answer (score 9):

The paper [Typed Self-Representation](https://www.informatik.uni-marburg.de/%7Ekos/papers/pldi142_rendel1.pdf) by Tillmann Rendel, Klaus Ostermann and    Christian Hofer seems to satisfy the requirements, and it's typed too. Perhaps it doesn't satisfy the criteria of being a simple model of computation.

Answer (score 6):

[Structural operational semantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_semantics#Structural_operational_semantics) is standard technology in theory of programming languages in which execution of a program is described as a series of transitions, each of which yields a valid program.

There are well-known mechanisms for dealing with or avoiding substitution in the execution of a program. Probably the most common one is that of keeping a run-time environment, which correspond to the subtitution we would have made so far, as well as to the run-time stack.

As far as homoiconicity is concerned, there are several options:

- In Kleene's number realizability each piece of data is represented by a number. This holds for machines themselves, so we have homoiconicity, as every infinite object (function with infinite domain, a real number, an infinite sequence) is represented by a number, which can be understood as its [Goedel code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goedel_code) or "source code".
- In theory of programming languages there are programming constructs that explicitely yield homoiconicity, for example the `quote`/`unqoute` mechanism in PCF+quote.
- The general buzz word you may want to look up is *meta programming*, see e.g. [this random paper](http://eprints.mdx.ac.uk/5929/1/Tratt-Program_Logics_for_Homogeneous_Meta-Programming-.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Version 1.5 of Lisp (1955) supports homoiconicity. It's not a *model* of computation but it could still be interesting.

Sidenote: I wrote an [implementation](https://github.com/parof/pilisp) of Lisp 1.5 that supports homoiconicity.